# Sql Express Backup and Restore to Different Server

Tags: sql-server

I have been translating an old ADP file format to a more current VB front end using Sql Express Backend.  In order to do the project the owners had me either VPN or Team Viewer in to a connected machine to run the software  As this was painfully slow.  I oersuaded them to let me create a bak file and then I would download that bak file and restore to my local sql express server.  I have had no issues.  Now I have never included the transaction log just the DB .  On my local copy I have added SP's and views and every time i do the restore the one I created that are not on the original server are still intact - which to my surprise and delight is great.  Ids this because I am not backing up the transition log or is there a different explanation?  Plus is it safe to assume any edits i have done locally to an SP or View whose name does exist in the original DB, will be overwritten?

Comment: I think we need more information.  When you created the `bak` from the source server, it automatically included enough of the transaction log to be able to recover the database to a transactionally-consistent view of the database at the time the data-reading portion of the backup finished when restored to the target server.  Restoring a database to your local server would completely overlay the original target database of the same name.  Perhaps you could update your question to include your backup and restore commands and provide a little more detail about what you are doing?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't create the stored procedure in the master database by accident?

Comment: A restore will completely overwrite the target database, including all schema and data from the backup. If you backup your local database after adding procs and views and then restore it to the customer's database, the new/changed procs and views will be included but all data changes made since the initial backup will also be overwritten.

Comment: No did not create restore in Master  I did a manual restore (taken from here as a best answer) which eliminated  several messages that while true , were not requirements for what I was doing.  So essentially if I created views or modified SP's I need to put them in the Original DB prior to doing the BU and restore?  The only reason I am doing this is to get the most current data , and generally this task is done by the admins for me and I am attached to their servers and sample DB's but that was not possible this time

Comment: Yes I went back and checked and under options I manually checked the overwrite , what an idiot  LOl  So to be clear if I make any schema changes, object creations or modifications - I need to put them in the Original as I do this?  Sounds like a good practice.